# insert checkboxlist value in database using (c#)ado.net

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net

i want to know how can i insert checkboxlist value in sql server database actually i know in asp.net how to insert checkboxlist value in database but im not getting in c#.net

```
foreach (ListBox lb in checkedListBox1.Items)
{
    if (lb.SelectedItem)
    {
        str += lb.ValueMember + ",";
    }
}
```

i just try above code but it give me error instead listitem im use listbox

Answer (score 0):

ListBox and CheckedListBox are two different controls.
Then you must create a connection to the database using ado.net and then a SqlCommand with insert. For be able to help you, you need to explain it more accurately.